# Is there a way to get past tumblr privacy policy acceptance page with HttpClient or similar?

Tags: c#, redirect, web-scraping

I've bee trying to get the html content of a tumblr blog in order to scrape some links off of it but every time I try to do it, I get **redirected** to their privacy policy page and have no idea how to proceed out of it.

I'm using HttpClient to access the blog page and in return I am getting [this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQCnl.jpg)

Here is the code I am using:

```
public static async Task<List<string>> GetLinksAsync()
{
    List<string> links = new List<string>();
    HttpClient request = new HttpClient();

    var repsonse = await request.GetAsync(_tumblrLink);

    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        //TODO process html and fill links
    }

    return links;
}
```

Is there a way to get past this? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just a guess but most likely if you add the required Cookie to your HttpClient bypass the Terms of Service. Although (second guess) this would be against the Terms of Service

Comment: Did you read it? e.g.: '(...) we and our partners need your consent to set cookies'.
Besides, what are the 'Terms of Service' writing about scraping some links? ;p

Comment: If you don't accept ToS you can't break it. ;) Try adding Cookie with request.

Comment: @colosso 
Tried the following:

`var baseUri = new Uri("https://aurora-daily.tumblr.com"); 
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cookie", "cookieHere");
                var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(baseUri);

                var rspContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }`

But I still get the same page as in the picture from the question. 
Also, am I supposed to place the cookie from the browser there? Or am I missing something.

Comment: @PreslavPanaiotov The thing is that you have to find out what the name and the expected value of the cookie is that you set in ´httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cookie", "cookieHere");´. I suggest you just clear all cookies in a browser, accept the ToS manually and check which cookies have been set. But keep in mind that whatever you do might be tracked if the cookie value is encrypted.

Comment: @nilsK Well... If I would write a WebScrapper that is against the ToS, I would not write in my question "I need help with my shady webscrapper"... No offense OP, but you never know ;)

Comment: @colosso I found the cookie in question along with it's name, tried copying it directly and got same result. Also took a look at the network traffic to see what was being sent, tried to send it with the same json format but again, no success.

`{
eu_resident:true, 
gdpr_is_acceptable_age:true, 
gdpr_consent_core:true, 
gdpr_consent_first_party_ads:true, 
gdpr_consent_third_party_ads:true, 
gdpr_consent_search_history:true, 
redirect_to:https://aurora-daily.tumblr.com/, 
gdpr_reconsent:false
}`

Looked something like this.